# How to simplify following SQL query to invoke count method only once?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following SQL code

```
select surname,
(select count(surname))  
from employees
group by surname
having count(surname) > 1
order by surname asc;
```

I need to invoke count method only once.

Comment: Don't worry about using `count()` more than once.  Let the database worry about optimization.

Comment: As Gordon Linoff notes, you don't need to bother with `count()`. And you don't need the sub-select. Just `select surname, count(surname) from employees
group by surname having count(surname) > 1 order by surname;`

Comment: On sqlfiddle it doesn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million ways to do that, but as Gordon pointed out: you shouldn't worry with count being executed multiple times - let the database take care of it. But if you somehow want to avoid writing it twice, try these options:

Subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT surname, count(surname) AS c 
   FROM employees GROUP BY surname) j
WHERE c > 1
ORDER BY surname
```

Or a CTE

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT surname, count(surname) AS c 
   FROM employees GROUP BY surname)  
SELECT * FROM j WHERE c > 1
ORDER BY surname
```

Comment: Thank you guys, Jim Jones answer's works perfectly. But my code with two duplicates show my poor knowledge about sql, i'm right? ;>

Answer (score 1):

This uses count() only once but uses a subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
         surname
        ,count(surname) as surname_count
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY
        surname
)
WHERE
    surname_count > 1
ORDER BY
    surname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem more complicated than needed, and the subquery construct seems useless in this case and may even slightly affect the performance.

Also

- you don't need to specify the "ASC" sort order, since it's the default
- you don't even need to type the field name twice in `count(surname)`, and can just type `count(*)`.

So try this :

```
SELECT surname, count(*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY surname
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY surname;
```

You can also try variations with `EXPLAIN` in front of your query to see exactly how Postgres procedes.